# Error converting data type varchar to bigint during update

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I need to update a bigint value in a database with a concatenation of two strings. SQL does not like this. DailyArchive.LogicalAccount is a bigint, @padding and a.AccountNumber are varchars.

```
Update dbo.DailyArchive 
SET DailyArchive.LogicalAccount = CONCAT(@padding, a.AccountNumber)
FROM @_AccountList a
JOIN dbo.DailyArchive ON a.AccountNumber = DailyArchive.LogicalAccount
```

I receive the following error message:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure updateNumbers_ArchiveDB, Line
>   15 Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

How I am executing the procedure:

```
declare @p1 dbo.AccountListType
insert into @p1 values(N'Account Number',N'Account Type')
insert into @p1 values(N'7463689',N'Basic')
insert into @p1 values(N'1317893',N'Premium')
insert into @p1 values(N'2806127',N'Basic')

exec updateNumbers_ArchiveDB
@_AccountList=@p1,
@padding=N'111',
@proc_dateStart='2008-01-04 11:24:46',
@proc_dateEnd='2008-01-04 11:24:46'
```

Comment: You're getting this error because some of the data in either @padding, a.AccountNumber, or both is not convertable to BIGINT.  Are you sure that neither of those values contains anything that is not a number?

Comment: Try `select CONCAT(@padding, a.AccountNumber)
FROM @_AccountList a
JOIN dbo.DailyArchive ON a.AccountNumber = DailyArchive.LogicalAccount` - do you see any that contain non-number characters?

Comment: Awfully sparse on details here. Either @padding, a.AccountNumber or DailyArchive.LogicalAccount has a row that is not a numeric string value.

Comment: Updated OP with how I am calling the procedure.

Comment: You appear to be inserting the column names to the table -`insert into @p1 values(N'Account Number',N'Account Type')`, So you are trying to convert `('111' + 'Account Number')` to a BIGINT. Remove this insert, and only insert valid data to your table and you should be fine.

Comment: Thats it. 

insert into @p1 values(N'Account Number',N'Account Type') will not convert to a bigint. Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line...

```
insert into @p1 values(N'Account Number',N'Account Type')
```

These will not convert into a `BIGINT`.

Even if a value is [`NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288080/error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-bigint-during-update#comment39409561_25288305), it would still be OK, since the `CONCAT` will just ignore it, ie...

`CONCAT(NULL,'111')` will give `111`.

Comment: That is what it was. You and @GarethD figured it out. Thanks.